# Getting a subset of a DataFrame that matches a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a DataFrame of this form:

```
                  time_stamp      src_ip           dst_ip
...
...
2430355  2019-05-28 23:19:25  10.0.0.125    34.236.210.83
2430356  2019-05-28 23:19:25   10.0.3.58      104.24.0.13
2430357  2019-05-28 23:19:25  10.0.0.100    23.200.101.62
2430358  2019-05-28 23:19:25    10.1.3.2   172.224.12.136
2430359  2019-05-28 23:19:25  10.1.0.234     104.16.48.55
...
...
```

and I am trying to get **rows** that match a certain **condition** within a **subset** of that DataFrame:

```
data.iloc[67048:67058][data.iloc[67048:67058]['dst_ip'] == '159.45.170.143']
```

(the subset being **[67048:67058]** and the condition **['dst_ip'] ==
'159.45.170.143']**)

This works fine but feels cumbersome. Is there a better way to perform this query?

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
data.iloc[67048:67058].query("dst_ip == '159.45.170.143'")
```

Comment: WeNYoBen, this leads to the following error:  raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as 'pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match.  I tried it before and this what got me to the convoluted version I mentioned in the first place.

Comment: For the people who downvote I have update my solution , thanks